# Including extended ASCII with regex and sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, extended-ascii

I want to select all characters, including extended ASCII inside a group of regex using sed.

- Next works:

```
echo -e "TO BE REMOVED. THIS NOT. TO BE REMOVED" | sed -E 's/(TO BE REMOVED)(.{12})(.*)/IT WAS REMOVED\2/g'
```

And I get:

```
IT WAS REMOVED. THIS NOT.
```

- But, if I insert an extended ASCII character inside one group, it doesn't work:

```
echo -e "TO BE REMOVED. THIS\xa5NOT. TO BE REMOVED" | sed -E 's/(TO BE REMOVED)(.{12})(.*)/IT WAS REMOVED\2/g'
```

- Trying to include extended ascii characters inside the sed regex, I can do the following:

```
echo -e "HI FRIEND, \xa5 ARE YOU?" | sed -E 's/\xa5/HOW/g'
```

This becomes:

```
HI FRIEND, HOW ARE YOU?
```

- But if I try to include all extended ascii characters with squared brackets, it doesn't work:

```
echo -e "HI FRIEND, \xa5 ARE YOU?" | sed -E 's/[\xa0-\xfe]/HOW/g'
```

I get the input

```
HI FRIEND,  ARE YOU?
```

Comment: `LANG=C sed 's/[\xa0-\xfe]/HOW/g'`, but hex escapes in sed aren't well supported you should use a bash expansion: `LANG=C sed 's/['$'\xa0-\xfe'']/HOW/g'`

Comment: Not sure that you can use `\xa0-\xfe` in a extended regexp for `sed`. When I try your example, I get _sed: -e expression #1, char 19: Invalid collation character_, using GNU sed 4.8; BTW, even if using `LANG=C`.

Comment: I get the Invalid collation error too. Perl is another option: `echo -e "HI FRIEND, \xa5 ARE YOU?" | perl -pe 's/[\xa0-\xfe]/HOW/g'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]/HOW/g' file
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for more information.